# PHP pull data out of mutiple databases

Tags: php, sql

I can't really figure this out.

1. Database 1
2. Database  2

   - table in database 1 : people `(ID, name, gender, DOB, state)`
   - table in database 2 : offenders `(ID, etc, etc)`

Now I need a query that gives me the (`name, gender, DOB, state`) if database 2 contains the same ID as database 1.

Should I use a innerjoin for this or what?

Thank you.

Comment: This could be solved with a simple sql join

Comment: Not necessarily.  He did say separate databases.  That option might not be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a join and calling database name in it :

```
SELECT t1.ID, name, gender, DOB, state, t2.stuff, t2.stuff2
FROM database1.people t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN database2.offenders t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: Great ! Think your DB schema as a tree view, it sometimes helps.